# Как правильно вставить переменные из lua в bash?

Tags: bash, lua

Как правильно вставить переменные из lua в bash?
Нужно скрипту передать 2 переменные, вот код:

```
location /script { 
content_by_lua '
  lua_arg1 = ngx.var.arg_arg1
  lua_arg2 = ngx.var.arg_arg2
  command = "/usr/bin/script.sh "..lua_arg1 ..lua_arg2
  local handle = io.popen(command);
  local result = handle:read("*a");
  handle:close();
  ngx.print(result);';
```

}

Вот запрос:
localhost:1501/script5?arg1=1234&arg2=4321

Вот bash скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo argument1 $1
echo argument2 $2
```

А вот результат:

```
argument1 12344321
argument2
```

Получается что переменные "склеились", как правильно их по отдельности передать в скрипт что бы было так:

```
argument1 1234
argument2 4321
```

Comment: а если в lua_arg1 будет '; rm -rf ~/' ?

Comment: Спасибо, решение уже нашел на другом форуме

Comment: command = "/usr/bin/script.sh "..lua_arg1 .. " " .. lua_arg2

Comment: так правильно будет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

очевидно, что надо вставить пробел между аргументами. ведь «слепляются» они в самом скрипте.

```
command = "/usr/bin/script.sh "..lua_arg1.." "..lua_arg2
```